# Newlines are lost when POST uploading using Jersey and JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey and JAX-RS to implement a REST POST endpoint. The actual servlet in `web.xml` is `com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet`. I then use JAX-RS to annotate my endpoint:

```
  @POST
  @Path("foo")
  public Response foo(Reader input) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(input);
    String line;
    while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }

    return Response.ok("{}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
  }
```

When I hit the endpoint a supply a text file, the newline characters are lost, and it's read in as one line. Example:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Prints out:

```
line 1line 2line 3
```

I tried annotating with `@Consumes("text/plain")` and setting the request header to `Content-Type:text/plain` but that doesn't help. Why are newline sequences being stripped?

Comment: From the result , it seems that the while loop is executed just once, can u try by putting a counter in the while loop, i think that the whole file is read as a single line string

Comment: Yes, the while loop iterates once because the newline characters aren't making it through

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using `curl` to upload, which apparently removes newlines

```
curl -v -X POST -d @input.txt http://localhost/foo
```

Using `--data-binary` instead resolved the issue.

```
curl -v -X POST --data-binary @input.txt http://localhost/foo
```

Comment: I have faced the same issue now.But i used android client to upload the text file.How to resolve this?